# Ways to boot faster in elementary OS

Tags: release-loki, boot

Good Morning everyone, how can i change the grub2 bootloader timeout? (direct command in terminal to change it to 0 sec) Also what are the other tips to make this boot faster?

Answer (score 1):

Open with your favorite text editor `/etc/default/grub` in `sudo` mode.

You'll see:
[image: /etc/default.grub]

`GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` stands for grub timeout. Change it to your desired value and save. :)

If you want to change sth more in grub then you have it here too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Systems with LVM partition enabled experience no timeout changes when setting GRUB_TIMEOUT. The reason is that grub lacks write support for LVM. Further info you can find at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120948/grub-recordfail-broken-regarding-lvm)

Adding a timeout for recordFail at /etc/default/grub in Grub should solve your issue:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0 >> /etc/default/grub'
sudo update-grub
```

It will add GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0 to /etc/default/grub file